# XDocument Attribute Performance Concerns

Tags: c#, .net, performance, caching, linq-to-xml

I have a loaded XDocument that I need to grab all the attributes that equal a certain value and is of a certain element efficiently. My current

```
IEnumerable<XElement> vm;
if (!cacher2.TryGetValue(name,out vm)) { 
    vm = project.Descendants(XName.Get(name));
    cacher2.Add(name, vm);
}


XElement[] abdl = (vm.Where(a =>  a.Attribute(attribute).Value == ab)).ToArray();
```

cacher2 is a `Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<XElement>>` The ToArray is so I can evaluate the expression now. I don't think this causes any real speed concerns. The problem is the Where itself.  I am searching through anywhere from 1k to 10k items.

Comment: Are you actually seeing any performance hits or are you concerned there may be one if your search set gets too big?

Comment: I am seeing huge its with the last line of code. The top lines are merely to show that I am caching as much as I can. There is more code to cache the result of abdl. I need to know what I need to convert this XDocument to, or what special methods to use to allow what I need to do... but faster. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to call `.ToArray`? I'm unclear on why you can't just loop over adding to the dictionary (or call `.ToDictionary`). However; have you profiled? If there *is* a bottleneck here, you might try dropping back to `XmlReader` and treating it as a firehose:

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element
                && reader.GetAttribute("attribName") == attribValue)
            {
                /* do something interesting for fun and profit */
            }
        }
```

With your existing code, though, I would be very tempted to make it:

```
vm.Where(a =>  (string)a.Attribute(attribute) == ab)
```

The difference is that by not calling `.Value` it should work even when the attribute isn't set. Of course if you *demand* that this attribute is always set then an exception may be acceptable in this case.

Comment: Do you know of any quick way to convert from my     vm = project.Descendants(XName.Get(name)); statement to an XmlReader?

I will try that and see if there is a change. I have profiled by the way, that single line of code is the bottleneck for my application. I understand reevaluating my needs, but for now this is the path I am taking.

Comment: The `while(reader.Read())` would be the heart of it. You can use `ReadSubtree` to get a child-reader to read nodes, so perhaps just use `XElement.Load(reader.ReadSubtree())` to get the nodes you care about?

Comment: I am using someXElement.CreateReader(); to create a new xmlreader every time I need to run this "query". Do you recommend I cache the reader and somehow set it back to the beginning when I'm done? Or should I create them when I need them?

Comment: @Dested - I'm talking about the data-volume where you don't have an `XElement` in the first place. If you've already parsed the xml into a DOM it is too late for such considerations.